# Multidimensional array sort by value

Tags: jquery, sorting, key

I have array like below:

Array
(
    [5263] => Array
        (
            [SOC026020] => 1
            [SOC045000] => 1
            [FIC022010] => 2
            [FIC030000] => 2

```
    )

[5098] => Array
    (
        [JUV026000] => 2
        [JUV015020] => 2
        [JUV039030] => 2
        [PER004010] => 1
        [PER004030] => 1
        [PER004020] => 1
        [FIC019000] => 3
        [FIC061000] => 1
        [JUV028000] => 1
    )

[5341] => Array
    (
         [FIC031000] => 2
        [JUV028000] => 4
    )
```

)

I need to sort like below:

Array
(
    [5263] => Array
        (
            [FIC022010] => 2
            [FIC030000] => 2
            [SOC026020] => 1
            [SOC045000] => 1

```
    )

[5098] => Array
    (
        [FIC019000] => 3
        [JUV026000] => 2
        [JUV015020] => 2
        [JUV039030] => 2
        [PER004010] => 1
        [PER004030] => 1
        [PER004020] => 1
        [FIC061000] => 1
        [JUV028000] => 1
    )

[5341] => Array
    (
        [JUV028000] => 4
        [FIC031000] => 2

    )
```

)

```js
I have array like below:

Array
(
    [5263] => Array
        (
            [SOC026020] => 1
            [SOC045000] => 1
            [FIC022010] => 2
            [FIC030000] => 2
         
        )

    [5098] => Array
        (
            [JUV026000] => 2
            [JUV015020] => 2
            [JUV039030] => 2
            [PER004010] => 1
            [PER004030] => 1
            [PER004020] => 1
            [FIC019000] => 3
            [FIC061000] => 1
            [JUV028000] => 1
        )

    [5341] => Array
        (
             [FIC031000] => 2
            [JUV028000] => 4
        )

  )
  
 I need to sort like below:
 
 Array
(
    [5263] => Array
        (
         [FIC022010] => 2
            [FIC030000] => 2
            [SOC026020] => 1
            [SOC045000] => 1
            
         
        )

    [5098] => Array
        (
         [FIC019000] => 3
            [JUV026000] => 2
            [JUV015020] => 2
            [JUV039030] => 2
            [PER004010] => 1
            [PER004030] => 1
            [PER004020] => 1
            [FIC061000] => 1
            [JUV028000] => 1
        )

    [5341] => Array
        (
         [JUV028000] => 4
         [FIC031000] => 2
            
        )

  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your inner array as below.

```
foreach($test as $key => $value){
      arsort($value);
      $test[$key] = $value; 
}
```

Hope this will helps you.